# Handling failover with StackExchange.Redis

Tags: c#, redis, stackexchange.redis

I am looking for validation of my approach, and pointers if I have missed anything.

My app has 2 redis connection multiplexers, one for redis instances, and one for sentinels.

On startup, I connect to a known sentinel address and query it for masters, then query it for slaves.

I then create the 'servers' connection using these discovered servers, and subscribe to the +master-switch and +promoted-slave channels on the sentinel.

If an even arrives from either of those channels, I simply go through the above discovery process again, replacing the connectionmultiplexers.

Now, Am I reinventing some functionality that SE.Redis already takes care of, or is there anything I have missed?

Thanks!

Comment: have you figured this out?

Comment: What are you trying to do?